# Javadocs for Uniobjects for Java

Tags: java, unidata, universe, uniobjects

I just started working with Rocket UniObjects and am looking for some Javadocs. Currently I am using the [Rocket Documentation](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/products/unidata/resources/manuals/unidata-7.2-documentation/java-v7r2.pdf), but I'm not a fan. I've looked, but had no luck. Has any one seen any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially what you've found is the only documentation they publish specifically for the Java UniObjects API.

There is a version of the document for UniVerse that might have slight insightful differences:

[UniVerse UniObjects for Java](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/products/universe/resources/technical-manuals/universe-v10r3/java-v10r3.pdf)

If you have .NET familiarity, you could take a look at the examples in the UniObjects for .NET documentation since the UniObjects API is relatively similar across the two languages:

[UniVerse UniObjects for .NET](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/products/universe/resources/technical-manuals/universe-v10r3/uonet-v10r3.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

We are working on improving several areas of our doc set for U2 (we have 100+ manuals) and unfortunately this one isn't on the immediate hit list.

There is a related effort however, which is to provide more examples for our products. We are using [GitHub](https://github.com/RocketSoftware/u2-servers-lab) for that. While there is only one example for UOJ at this time, you can [raise an issue](https://github.com/RocketSoftware/u2-servers-lab/issues) with what sample would help you out so are team hears first hand what people are looking for in our examples.